# Android SQLite case sensitive look-up

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, case-sensitive

EDIT: I found the answer. Use "GLOB". What a weird word, no wonder I can't find anything.

I am trying to use a cursor in Android to do a case sensitive lookup of my SQLite table. I have googled for it but all results are of people asking on how to get case insensitive lookup and tutorials on how to make it case-insensitive. That is the opposite of what I want. I want a case sensitive look-up, but I am still learning SQLite and don't know what to add.

This is how my cursor is currently called:

```
c = getContentResolver().query(element, null, PeriodicTable.SYMBOL + " LIKE? ", new String[]{guess}, "symbol");
```

Elements in the periodic table are case sensitive, so if you enter CO, you get Carbon and Oxygen. If you enter Co, you get Cobalt. I want to use case sensitivity to filter out erroneous user entries.

Comment: There is no such a thing like `Carbon and Oxygen` (CO) in the periodic table. There is `Carbon` (C) and there is `Oxygen` (O). And there is `Cobalt` (Co). Therefore, if you enter `CO` or `co` or `cO` or `Co` you will always get `Cobalt`. Why should you use `LIKE` or `GLOB`, when you can use `=`?

Comment: @Frank N. Stein Thanks for the help, I didn't know I could use = in place if LIKE. What is the difference? I am writing a parsing algorithm for chemical formulas, so I have to "guess" the current element as a combination of the current character and the next, which can result in CO, Co, cO, and co.

Comment: `Like` uses "regular expressions" (well, **kind of**). While `=` is a strict equivalence (therefore it's **faster**, because it does a single comparison).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the case-sensitivity of the built-in `LIKE` expression to `ON` before executing your query

```
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON", null);
```

then,

```
c = getContentResolver().query(element, null, PeriodicTable.SYMBOL + " LIKE? ", new String[]{guess}, "symbol");
```

later, revert the case-sensitivity of `LIKE` to the default value, `OFF`

```
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=OFF", null);
```

Let me know if this helps !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out case sensitive look-up uses "GLOB" instead of "LIKE". I would have to make extra code if I use rawQuery since I am using contentProvider for my SQLite table. But if I use "GLOB" I don't need to.